# CakePHP: Rendering an undefined index

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've debugged the view page just to confirm the data were properly collected. And indeed I have this:

```
 [Friend] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [username] => James_Baker
                            [password] => 7pooplllLLKMKMKKkss09koskld1d9b5e6
                            [first_name] => James
                            [last_name] => Baker
                            [email] => D-W-James@yahoo.com
                            [group_id] => 2
                            [created] => 2011-01-10 08:25:52
                            [modified] => 2011-02-04 17:30:47
                            [slug] => 
                 ....
                 ....
```

As I tried displaying on my view page, from my view.ctp here's what I currently use:

```
..
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user['Friend']['username']; ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
..
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined index: username
```

Can someone fix the error based on the debug code I have ? I'm trying to output/echo the friend's username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct key to call this value is `$user['Friend'][0]['username']`

To debug use `var_dump($user); exit;` just after you start every loop.

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
     <h1>User Friends</h1>
     <?php foreach ($user['Friend'] as $friend): ?>
         <?php echo $friend['username']; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: to debug, better use pr() or debug()

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want $user['Friend'][0]['username']